# Particular types of basis on a normed vector space of finite dimension

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Is it true that on every normed vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ there exists a basis of  norm $1$ vectors $v_i$, such that $\|\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_iv_i\|\geq 1$ for all possible combinations of $\epsilon_i=\pm 1$? Clearly this is true for an orthonormal basis and it is also not hard to show that it is true if $n=2$.

Comment: Take the unit ball in your norm and take the circumscribed parallelepiped of the least volume. The points of tangency will lie at the centers of its faces and thus produce the basis you are looking for.

Comment: Fedja just gave you the construction that prove's Auerbach's lemma.

Comment: Great, thank you! I was hoping that a result like this exists. 

Comment: Is there a way to close questions like this, which are answered in comments?